# swiper plugin is delaying to load about 30 to 60 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, swiper.js, idangero

i have a website that use this template https://ld-wp.template-help.com/wordpress_63613/ and the problem is in the previous link .. the news div is loading about 30 to 60 seconds late than all the page contents .. you just can browse the link and view the problem

i will attach screen shots

i see that the template uses swiper plugin from  * http://www.idangero.us/swiper/

i tried to download the original css and js files but i does not work

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <!-- Slide-->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <div class="post-meta post-date">
                        <a href="2016/10/27/27.html" class="post__date-link"><time datetime="2016-10-27T10:21:25+00:00">October 27, 2016</time></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-meta post-comments"><a href="quadrennial-dinner-breaks-numerous-records-raises-5-million.html#comments" class="post__comments-link">3 comments</a></div>
                </div>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <div class="post-thumbnail">
                        <a href="quadrennial-dinner-breaks-numerous-records-raises-5-million.html" class="post-thumbnail__link"><img class="post-thumbnail__img" src="wp-content/uploads/2016/10/img-3-390x303.jpg" alt="Bedayia School Celebrates 100 days with their Students" width="390" height="303"></a>
                    </div>
                    <h5 class="entry-title"><a href="quadrennial-dinner-breaks-numerous-records-raises-5-million.html" title="Bedayia School Celebrates 100 days with their Students">Bedayia School Celebrates 100 days with their Students</a></h5>
                </header>
                <article class="entry-content">
                    <p>Gr 1 & 2 students during the Speak up campaign ceremony & Student Honor roll Gr 1 & 2 students during the Speak up campaign ceremony & Student Honor roll</p>
                </article>
            </div>
            <footer class="entry-footer"></footer>
        </div>
        <!-- Slide-->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <div class="post-meta post-date">
                        <a href="2016/10/19/19.html" class="post__date-link"><time datetime="2016-10-19T10:20:30+00:00">October 19, 2016</time></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-meta post-comments"><a href="quadrennial-dinner-breaks-numerous-records-raises-5-million.html#respond" class="post__comments-link">0 comments</a></div>
                </div>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <div class="post-thumbnail">
                        <a href="quadrennial-dinner-breaks-numerous-records-raises-5-million.html" class="post-thumbnail__link"><img class="post-thumbnail__img" src="wp-content/uploads/2016/10/img-6-390x303.jpg" alt="Bedaya School added 33 new photos to the album: Animal Show." width="390" height="303"></a>
                    </div>
                    <h5 class="entry-title"><a href="quadrennial-dinner-breaks-numerous-records-raises-5-million.html" title="Bedaya School added 33 new photos to the album: Animal Show.">Bedaya School added 33 new photos to the album: Animal Show.</a></h5>
                </header>
                <article class="entry-content">
                    <p>In BIS we focus on representing the new concepts by practicing real life experiences that help the students to make connections between the world and their studies .</p>
                </article>
            </div>
            <footer class="entry-footer"></footer>
        </div>
        <!-- Slide-->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <div class="post-meta post-date">
                        <a href="2016/10/03/03.html" class="post__date-link"><time datetime="2016-10-03T10:16:05+00:00">October 3, 2016</time></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-meta post-comments"><a href="lus-commencement-2016.html#respond" class="post__comments-link">0 comments</a></div>
                </div>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <div class="post-thumbnail">
                        <a href="lus-commencement-2016.html" class="post-thumbnail__link"><img class="post-thumbnail__img" src="wp-content/uploads/2016/10/img-7-390x303.jpg" alt="LU&#039;s commencement 2016" width="390" height="303"></a>
                    </div>
                    <h5 class="entry-title"><a href="lus-commencement-2016.html" title="Bedaya School's commencement 2016">Bedaya School's commencement 2016</a></h5>
                </header>
                <article class="entry-content">
                    <p>This year the commencement at the Bedayia School has been the biggest in its&hellip;</p>
                </article>
            </div>
            <footer class="entry-footer"></footer>
        </div>
        <!-- Slide-->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <div class="post-meta post-date">
                        <a href="2016/09/22/22.html" class="post__date-link"><time datetime="2016-09-22T10:13:29+00:00">September 22, 2016</time></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-meta post-comments"><a href="professor-kenobi-at-the-yale-conference-2016.html#respond" class="post__comments-link">0 comments</a></div>
                </div>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <div class="post-thumbnail">
                        <a href="professor-kenobi-at-the-yale-conference-2016.html" class="post-thumbnail__link"><img class="post-thumbnail__img" src="wp-content/uploads/2016/10/img-10-390x303.jpg" alt="Professor Kenobi at the Yale Conference 2016" width="390" height="303"></a>
                    </div>
                    <h5 class="entry-title"><a href="professor-kenobi-at-the-yale-conference-2016.html" title="Professor Kenobi at the Yale Conference 2016">Professor Kenobi at the Yale Conference 2016</a></h5>
                </header>
                <article class="entry-content">
                    <p>This spring the Bedaya School&#8217;s professor and the SPS business school dean Michelle Kenobi visited&hellip;</p>
                </article>
            </div>
            <footer class="entry-footer"></footer>
        </div>
        <!-- Slide-->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <div class="post-meta post-date">
                        <a href="2016/09/15/15.html" class="post__date-link"><time datetime="2016-09-15T10:11:21+00:00">September 15, 2016</time></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-meta post-comments"><a href="law-school-expansion.html#respond" class="post__comments-link">0 comments</a></div>
                </div>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <div class="post-thumbnail">
                        <a href="law-school-expansion.html" class="post-thumbnail__link"><img class="post-thumbnail__img" src="wp-content/uploads/2016/10/img-9-390x303.jpg" alt="Law school expansion" width="390" height="303"></a>
                    </div>
                    <h5 class="entry-title"><a href="law-school-expansion.html" title="Law school expansion">Law school expansion</a></h5>
                </header>
                <article class="entry-content">
                    <p>As the submission process for this year has already wrapped up, we can see&hellip;</p>
                </article>
            </div>
            <footer class="entry-footer"></footer>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"><i class="linearicon linearicon-chevron-left"></i></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"><i class="linearicon linearicon-chevron-right"></i></div>
</div>
```

when it first loaded it becomes like this for 30 to 60 seconds depending on network speed
[image]

then it loads but after a long time of white space on the design
[image]

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error, are you sure about it?

Answer (score 0):

No space between attributes. 
JavaScript is parsed during initial page load. Defer parsing JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering.

Comment: which attributes